# merge two asp.net applications into one keeping urls

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have two asp.net apps e.g. server/app1/ and server/app2/. Now we want to merge these apps together, but we also need to keep the old urls working.

Is it possible to have a single app handling requests to both server/app1/ and server/app2/ without installing it as the root app? Is there a good solution?

Comment: If the applications are MVC applications, you can use [Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx). When pointing both websites (app1/app2) to the same application directory, you can use IIS-wide URL rewriting to properly channel the requests to the areas.

Comment: @fjdumont: I guess URL rewriting would do the trick but when I looked into this I couldn't find how to configure it automatically (by the installer) so I thought maybe there is a simpler solution...